# How to get first image in string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to get first image in string using javascript ?

my string is

```
    <p>Hello</p>
<p style="text-align: center; "><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png" alt=""><br></p>
<p style="text-align: center; ">Hello</p><br>
<p style="text-align: center; "><img src="https://www.google.co.th/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" alt=""><br></p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Hello World</p><br><br><br>
```

I want to get first image url in this case is [image]

I tried to search on stackoverflow for hours but not found how to do please help me, how can i do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to append a markup in hidden div and use [**`Element.querySelector`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to select the element and get its respective property.

```js
var str = "<p>Hello</p><p style=\"text-align: center; \"><img src=\"https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png\" alt=\"\"><br></p><p style=\"text-align: center; \">Hello</p><br><p style=\"text-align: center; \"><img src=\"https://www.google.co.th/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png\" alt=\"\"><br></p><p style=\"text-align: left;\">Hello World</p><br><br><br>";
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(elem);
elem.innerHTML = str;
console.log(elem.querySelector('img').src);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple approach

- **Create a `div`** (don't add it to body's DOM)
- set `innerHTML` as your string
- do `querySelector` to fetch first `img`.

**Demo**

```js
var str = ` <p>Hello</p>
<p style="text-align: center; "><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png" alt=""><br></p>
<p style="text-align: center; ">Hello</p><br>
<p style="text-align: center; "><img src="https://www.google.co.th/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" alt=""><br></p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Hello World</p><br><br><br>`;

var ele = document.createElement("div");
ele.innerHTML = str;
var image = ele.querySelector("img");
console.log(image.outerHTML);
```

> I want to get first image url in this case is

```
  console.log(image.src);
```

Comment: Aah... I missed it :P

Comment: @Rayon Not by much though and you were faster as well +1

Answer (score 0):

Hi try following code

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution...

`document.querySelector('img')`

Answer (score 0):

The nost reliable way to do this is by letting the browser parse the string into DOM:

```
let html = document.createElement('html');
html.innerHTML = you_string;
```

Then you can use jquery for example:

```
let first = $('img', html)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to to the image,

```
<img id="someid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png" alt="">
```

and you can get the image and its source in js as

```
var image = document.getElementById("someid");
var imageSrc = image.currentSrc;
```